# Google Groups Provisioning: What am I missing here?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-provisioning-api

I'm trying to add a member to a Google group using the provision API.  I've ran this in python with no success.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here... anybody?

```
import gdata.apps.groups.client
groupClient = gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/2.0/testtgroup123456')
groupClient.ClientLogin(email='myEmail@email.com', password='myPassword', source='apps')
groupClient.AddMemberToGroup('testtgroup123456', 'emailtoadd@email.com')
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to answer my own thread.  I just realized that provisioning is only for google app business and education accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has recently added support for the Provisioning API to Standard/Free accounts. The domain parameter for GroupsProvisioningClient() should be your actual domain:

```
import gdata.apps.groups.client
groupClient = gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain='email.com')
groupClient.ClientLogin(email='myEmail@email.com', password='myPassword', source='apps')
groupClient.AddMemberToGroup('testtgroup123456', 'emailtoadd@email.com')
```

I've confirmed [GAM](http://ditoweb.com/dito-gam) allows me to provision groups for my Google Apps Standard domain using the same APIs

Comment: Back to work on this.  Tested and unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working for me. edit* for the domain, i've tested the following 'gmail.com', 'groups.google.com', and 'google.com'... still no success

Comment: Update: I signed up for Google Apps for Business and this is still not working... wtf.

Comment: domain should be your Google Apps domain, not google.com or gmail.com.  You are using a Google Apps Group, not a consumer Google Group with a @googlegroups.com email address aren't you?

Comment: Sorry I got this working, my problem was I somehow managed to forget to put gdata in my site packages folder.

Comment: Sorry Jay, I have a number of threads open and I think I was trying to answer ones that were not accepted yet.. got this one by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Google provisioning is only for Google business and education accounts.